# how can i fix error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires 6 type argument(s)

Tags: angular, node-modules

[image: these are the errors i get when i run the project :]

[image: and this is the version of dependencies i use :]

I was working on the project and there is no problem ..and suddenly when I pasted a template in another component. That component didn't recognize the elements of angular material. and then the whole project stopped recognizing the angular material selectors. Now I have node module errors.

I have tried `npm install` and `npm audit fix --force` and it still the same error. what should I do?

Comment: Did you try Angular material 13 yet? Seem like your Angular and Angular material is mismatch, it may cause the issue.

Comment: i'm using angular material 14 . i have run the command 'npm outdated'  to see if there is any outdated dependency and i updated the wanted version of each @angular-devkit/build-angular  , angular-material , Karma and @angular/core but it didn't help .

Comment: should i remove the node modules and reinstall it ?

Answer (score 4):

I had same error and solved it by this command

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

1. `npm outdated`
   [image]
2. `ng update`
   [image]
3. `ng update @angular/cli`
4. `npm outdated` (after update @angular/cli and @angular/core)
   [image]